# Mazda Demio Rattling/Knocking sound

Tags: noise, mazda

I recently bought a Japan imported Mazda Demio (has around 30,000km in mileage and is in a pretty good condition). From the very start, I noticed a small rattling / knocking sound coming from the front of the car. I am not sure if its from either tyres or just from the front of the car, under steering wheel or so. The sound that it makes (though its surely not the best way to describe it) is similar to this: 'thrrrrrr thrrrrrr thrrrrrr'

It's not a big sound but it happens when I pass from rough surfaced roads - mostly where there are small bumps. The sound is more audible when the car is moving slowly and when the bump is not so big.

It sounds like something is loose, and doesn't sound like a damaged part. It does not bother me too much but I thought I'd get some opinions on what it might be.

The car is under warranty from the dealer I've bought it from, so sooner rather than later Ill probably end up getting checked just the same, but your opinions or similar experiences with similar cars are greatly appreciated.